# Assign value of a reference property to a variable

Tags: c#, ref, value-type

I have a scenario where I want to pass in a reference of the value type `bool` (value type marked with `ref`) to a constructor of an other class and want to update its value in the other class. Something like this. Is there a way to hold the reference of the variable. (I marked things with public, and I know that public variables can be accessed from anywhere)

```
public class A
{
    public bool Update;
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        B b = new B(ref Update);
    }
}

public class B
{
    private ref bool _val; //Is it possible to create a variable like this. If not is there a way to achieve what I am doing.
    public B(ref bool value)
    {
        _val = value;
    }
    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        _val = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: I am not clear on what you are trying to do.  Are you wanting the value of field Update in class A to be changed when field _val in class B is changed?

Comment: You can't store a `ref` in a class. But something I always wanted is a `boxed bool`. The solution here is to pass through either an object containing the bool or a delegate that can change it in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap value with the reference type

```
public class CanUpdate
{
    public bool Value { get; set; }
}
```

Then

```
public class B
{
    private readonly CanUpdate _canUpdate;

    public B(CanUpdate value)
    {
        _canUpdate = value;
    }

    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        _canUpdate.Value = true;
    }
}
```

Class `A` will "see" value changed by class `B`

```
public class A
{
    private CanUpdate CanUpdate;

    public A()
    {
        CanUpdate = new CanUpdate { Value = false };
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(CanUpdate.Value); // false

        var b = new B(CanUpdate);
        b.UpdateValue();

        Console.WriteLine(CanUpdate.Value); // true
    }
}
```

Having own dedicated type for a value improves readability and makes code more comprehensible for others.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the value only once, then just have it once. Delegate from one class to the other, either from A to B or vice versa.

```
public class A
{
    B b = new B(false);
    public bool Update { 
        get { return b.BooleanValue; }
    }

    public void DoSomething()
    {

    }
}

public class B
{
    public B(bool value)
    {
        _val = value;
    }
    private void UpdateValue()
    {
        _val = true;
    }

    public bool BooleanValue{ 
        get { return _val; }
    }
}
```

If the use of B is really as temporary as

```
public void DoSomething()
{
    B b = new B(ref Update);
}
```

then let B a method of B return the boolean.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to set a field as a reference type (`private ref bool _val;`) since it is just a class scoped variable. Property setters don't allow you to add the `ref` modifier to the automatic `value` parameter, so that would not work either. Furthermore, you cannot pass a property as a `ref` parameter (i.e. `obj1.Method(ref obj2.Value)` will not work).

I think what you are trying to describe is the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern), where **observers** watch for changes in a **subject's** state and react. It's similar to an event listener in JavaScript, but instead of watching **actions**, you are watching **state**. A simple implementation of this might look like:

```cs
public class Subject
{
    private readonly Observer[] Observers;
    private string _val;
    public string Val
    {
        get => _val;
        set
        {
            // Update every observer's value when this is set.
            foreach (Observer o in Observers)
            {
                o.Val = value;
            }
            _val = value;
        }
    }
    public Subject(params Observer[] observers)
    {
        Observers = observers;
    }
}

public class Observer
{
    public string Val { get; set; }
}

// In execution:
var o1 = new Observer();
var o2 = new Observer();
var subject = new Subject(o1, o2);
subject.Val = "hello there";
Console.WriteLine("o1: " + o1.Val);
Console.WriteLine("o2: " + o2.Val);
Console.WriteLine("subject: " + subject.Val);

// Output:
// o1: hello there
// o2: hello there
// subject: hello there
```

Note this particular case has some limitations since the relationship only works from `Subscriber` to `Observer` (i.e., if you change the Observer's `Val` directly, it won't be reflected by the other observers and further updates to Subject will overwrite any changes to Observer).

Comment: I wouldn't say "It doesn't make sense to set a field as a ref", it is only disallowed by ECMA-335 standard because it may leak a stack pointer to the heap. C++ uses it the whole time, but it's unsafe for managed pointers.

Comment: I have WPF app in which I need to update just one boolean property that is bound to a progress bar from a child class. So I didn't want to pass in the entire object as B b=new B(this), I just wanted to see if there was a way to pass in a ref parameter when an action in a child class executes. I also don't want to raise events. I know the observer pattern.Thanks for the help.